# Visual Studio Code freezes

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just installed Vs Code on Ubuntu for the first time, but when I open it, it freezes and says "Visual Studio Code is not responding". I uninstalled it and reinstalled it, updated it and after a long list of things that unfortunately didn't help me, I'm here.
I even thought to install another code editor.

What can I do? I'm unhinged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use vscode official website and download the tar.gz extract it and then ready to goo